# Thymeleaf read property inside a replace

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code, where tdk is a common variable I have defined in the SpringBoot file `application.properties` named `server.contextPath`

I would like to know if there is a way to replace it for

```
<head th:replace="tdk/common/header :: common-header" />
```

something like

```
<head th:replace="@environment.get('server.contextPath')/common/header :: common-header" />
```

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also tried :

```
<head th:replace="~{${@environment.getProperty('serverContextPath') + '/common/header'} :: common-header}" />
```

with this result:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "~{${@environment.getProperty('serverContextPath') + '/common/header'}", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (/tdk/registration/signup:6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using thymeleaf 3, you can accomplish this using [fragment expressions](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451).  I think it should look something like this:

```
<head th:replace="~{${@environment.getProperty('myPropertyName') + '/common/header'} :: common-header}" />
```

Comment: "~{${@environment.getProperty('server.contextPath') + '/common/header'}", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (/tdk/login/login:6)
 at

Comment: Well, have you verified that the string generated matches what you actually want?  I can't verify the value @environment.getProperty('server.contextPath').

Comment: it seems that it does not replace the variable

Comment: Does @environment.getProperty('myPropertyName') resolve in other expressions?

Comment: yes, for instance here it works: th:attr="placeholder=${@environment.getProperty('server.contextPath')}"

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada -- I verified this solution works using these settings: in a property file: `template=included`, using this expression: `<section th:replace="~{${@environment.getProperty('template')} :: heythere}" />` and in an html file `included.html`: `<div th:fragment="heythere">Hey THERE!!</div>` and everything worked for me... but I can't really debug your app.